# Error in writing a simple insert function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Not sure why but I keep getting this error: `Error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` when I am trying to write an insert function below.

```
 BEGIN
      IF NEW.email NOT LIKE '%@test.com%' THEN
        INSERT INTO user (id, email)
        VALUES (
          NEW.id,
          NEW.email
        );
      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
  END;
```

any suggestion will be really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: That piece of code can never cause that error. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you have a trigger that is doing something else

Comment: Thanks for the response. yeah. I am looking into something else.